# Main function of complex number class C++

Tags: c++

I am working on an assignment for C++, I am very new to this language. The assignment is about implementing Newton Raphson Method for a function with complex roots. I have implemented the code.

I want to test my code now and I am having difficulty in getting my main function to work properly, there are some concepts I am not understanding that lead to my wrong implementation. I would appreciate some explanations so I can understand better. Thanks.

This is the example of my code:

Complex.h

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath>

using namespace std;

class Complex {
    private:
    double r;
    double i;

    public:
    Complex(double real, double imaginary);
    friend Complex operator+(const Complex& c1, const Complex& c2);
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& outs, const Complex& number);       
};
```

Complex.cpp

```
#include "testComplex.h"

Complex::Complex(double real = 0.0, double imaginary = 0.0) : r(real), i(imaginary) {}
Complex operator+(const Complex& c1, const Complex& c2) {
    Complex result;
    result.r = c1.r + c2.r;
    result.i = c1.i + c2.i;
    return result;
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "testComplex.h"

using namespace std;

int main () {
    Complex x;
    Complex y;
    Complex sum;
    x = Complex(2, 4);
    y = Complex(3, 0);
    sum = x + y;
    cout << "The sum (x + y) is:  " << sum << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This is a part of the error that I am receiving:

```
testComplexmain.cc: In function ‘int main()’:
testComplexmain.cc:8:10: error: no matching function for call to ‘Complex::Complex()’
testComplexmain.cc:8:10: note: candidates are:
testComplex.h:15:2: note: Complex::Complex(double, double)
testComplex.h:15:2: note:   candidate expects 2 arguments, 0 provided
testComplex.h:8:7: note: Complex::Complex(const Complex&)
testComplex.h:8:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
testComplexmain.cc:9:10: error: no matching function for call to ‘Complex::Complex()’
```

Comment: Your Complex.h file has no default constructor so when you say `Complex result;` you get an error as your only defined declaration invovles two doubles

Comment: Move the `= 0.0` default parameter values from the .cpp file to the header file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have a default constructor because you put the default parameters in the definition, so you can only construct `Complex` instances by passing two parameters.

You could add a default constructor,

```
Complex() : r(0), i(0) {}
```

or put the default parameters in the function declaration instead of in the definition

```
Complex(double real = 0.0, double imaginary = 0.0);
```

or write your code like this:

```
int main () {
    Complex x(2, 4);
    Complex y(3, 0);
    Complex sum = x + y;
    cout << "The sum (x + y) is:  " << sum << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explanation. That's strange, now I get this error  but as far as I see, I am calling Complex correctly:`testComplex.cc: In function ‘Complex operator+(const Complex&, const Complex&)’:
testComplex.cc:33:10: error: call of overloaded ‘Complex()’ is ambiguous
testComplex.cc:33:10: note: candidates are:
testComplex.cc:27:1: note: Complex::Complex(double, double)
testComplex.cc:17:2: note: Complex::Complex()`

Comment: Add a default constructor *or* put the default parameters in the function declaration. You can't do both.

Comment: Note: the main version shown by @molbdnilo here is much more idiomatic than your version. It is good style to declare variables as late as possible, and immediately initialize them.

That said, you still want a default constructor.

Comment: @FabioFracassi The usual way of getting a default constructor for something like `Complex` would be to provide default arguments for the parameters of the normal constructor; i.e. `Complex( double read = 0.0, double imaginary = 0.0 )`.  (This also provides implicit conversion of `double` to `Complex`.)

Comment: @JamesKanze Yes, sure. My point was that the idiomatic usage of `Complex` in `main()` should not require a default ctor at all, but that even though it is not needed for the OP's example it is still a good idea to provide one (and I agree that in this case default parameters are to be prefered)

Answer (score 6):

You don't have a default constructor. The two-argument constructor could be used as one, since both arguments are optional; but you'll have to put the default arguments on the declaration in the header, not the definition in the source file, for them to be usable from `main`.

Personally, I'd use `std::complex` rather than reinventing it.